# Bootstrap: Nested column disappears after breaking point is reached

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a grid with 3 columns, in each of this columns there is a nested grid with 2 columns (one smaller than the other one).

I want the columns to stack up on the top of each other once the breakpoint is reached. But for some reason, one of the nested columns disappears after the breakpoint.

Here is what I did:

```css
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-4">
          icon
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-8">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-4">
          icon
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-8">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-4">
          icon
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-8">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, in the snippet I made for this thread, nested columns stack up but not the parent ones. Meanwhile, on my website parent columns stack up but the main issue is that the column with the icon completely disappears once the large breakpoint is reached.

What I want it to look like, once the large breakpoint is reached, is the following:

[Nested layout once breakpoint is reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Efv.png)

Instead, this is what happens:

[Screen record of my layout on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOtdj.gif)

Considering the fact that this is the first time I use bootstrap it's no surprise I am doing something very wrong, but what in particular? Is anybody able to show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used a lot of rows that were intertwined. That's unnecessary. You can solve your problem by using columns in a single row.

I also recommend removing the "padding:40px" feature and re-examining it for the example you share here. Because the Padding is too much, the items cannot fit into the 12-column grid system.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <!-- d-flex added-->

    <!-- First Column -->
    <div class=" padding col-sm-12 col-lg-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="200" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/investment-26/64/investment-16-512.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class=" padding col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <h2>Usability</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium sed vitae corrupti modi quam tempore, aut, reprehenderit praesentium odio sint recusandae eos voluptatibus ut beatae assumenda dignissimos explicabo hic voluptatum.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Column -->
    <div class="padding col-sm-12 col-lg-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="200" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/investment-26/64/investment-16-512.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="padding col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <h2>Parallax effect</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium sed vitae corrupti modi quam tempore, aut, reprehenderit praesentium odio sint recusandae eos voluptatibus ut beatae assumenda dignissimos explicabo hic voluptatum.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Third Column -->
    <div class="padding col-sm-12 col-lg-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="200" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/investment-26/64/investment-16-512.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="padding col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <h2>Unlimites colors</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium sed vitae corrupti modi quam tempore, aut, reprehenderit praesentium odio sint recusandae eos voluptatibus ut beatae assumenda dignissimos explicabo hic voluptatum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I realised this  not long after I made my question. I was minding my business in my bathroom and I had the Eureka! God knows why I always have them in the most ridiculous times! As you said, for what I am trying to achieve there is absolutely no need to nest columns but instead make 6 different ones that will stack up once the large breakpoint is reached. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: Also, there was no padding in my original layout, it was inserted here to show the layout. Many thanks for the insight on the d-flex options, it's a life saver!

Comment: I like the fact that items get aligned once the breakpoint is reached but none of this happens on my website, is there any particular reason? I use bootstrap 4.5

Comment: Hi, I'm glad I could help. What problems do you have with Breakpoints ? What's not working properly ? I suggest you check Media query if you've written something that will affect it.

Comment: Once the breakpoint is reached it doesn't align items in the center like in your layout. I tried _align-items-lg-center_ and _justify-content-lg-center_ and also both at the same time. I added them to the row but they won't align. 

I don't have any media queries written so far that could make a conflict